# keep MYSQL connection functional for multiple queries

Tags: mysql, c, raspberry-pi

I am having a very hard time finding information on this topic. I have a running application on a Raspberry Pi where I have an infinite loop with the below code. outside of it i have the `MYSQL *con;` to be reused. So my code works well the first time, but the second time i get the following error. I thought adding the `MYSQL_close()` would do the trick but it didn't.

output:

```
valor: d9274cb5   -651735883
valor: d9274cb5   -651735883
1
This handle is already connected. Use a separate handle for each connection.
```

code:

```
                    uint32_t intVal;
                    sscanf(&sn_str[1],"%x",&intVal);
                    fprintf(stderr, "valor: %x   %d\n", intVal, intVal);
                    if (mysql_real_connect(con, "localhost", "rfid", "******",
                            "Order2Dock", 0, NULL, 0) == NULL)
                    {
                            fprintf(stderr, "1 \n");
                            finish_with_error(con);
                    }
                    if (mysql_query(con, "INSERT INTO `Order2Dock`.`Actividad`(`TiempoInicio`,`Proceso_Id`, `Orden_Id`)     VALUES (now(),1,1)")) {
                            fprintf(stderr, "2 \n");
                            finish_with_error(con);
                    }
                    mysql_close(con);
```

Comment: shot in the dark, what happens if you add mysql_close(con) before that 1st if statement to see if something reconnecting &con outside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your connect command outside of the loop

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
if (!$mysqli) {
 fprintf(stderr, "1 \n");
 finish_with_error(con);
}
```

Then start the loop, you dont need to connect everytime you loop:

```
while (1+1 = 2){
 if (!$mysqli){ 
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
 }
 uint32_t intVal;
 sscanf(&sn_str[1],"%x",&intVal);
 fprintf(stderr, "valor: %x   %d\n", intVal, intVal);
 if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `Order2Dock`.`Actividad`(`TiempoInicio`,`Proceso_Id`, `Orden_Id`) VALUES (now(),1,1)") === TRUE) {
  echo '<p>Yeah, another query!!</p>';
 }
}
```

Edit: I just added a condition to test if the link is still up, otherwise re-connect to the database.

I was just thinking that if this is an infinite loop running over a Web server like apache or IIS... then something must be configured in order to let the script run forever instead and prevent the web server from timing it out.

Cheers.

Comment: this did work, is it safe to have a connection open the whole time?

Comment: It's safe as long as you keep using it... you can add a check to see if it's still open, something like `if (!$mysqli->connect_errno) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
    }` will do

Answer (score 0):

[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_multi_query.asp)

[php refrerence](http://php.net/manual/kr/mysqli.multi-query.php)

I heard "mysql" will be deleted on future php..
using "mysqli" and you can use mysqli_multi_query

Comment: @pato.llaguno ah.. I am really sorry.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: @pato.llaguno you have to do mysql_free_result() after using